# CKEditor - detect which buttons are pressed

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

When I need to edit existing text stored in the database, some buttons on the CKeditor toolbar are pressed as they already have some styles.

For instance, if I have the following text in my database:

```
<strong>asdf</strong>
```

when I edit this text, the "bold" button is pressed.

I need to set `bulletedlist` clicked as the default setting of my editor. I listen to the `instanceReady` event and use `execCommand('bulletedlist')` when the event is on to achieve my goal:

```
CKEDITOR.on( 'instanceReady',function(ev) {
  ev.editor.execCommand( 'bulletedlist' );
} );
```

however, if the text is already bulleted, calling `execCommand('bulletedlist')` will cancel the bulleted style.
I need to know which buttons are pressed when users start editing the text, so I can prevent canceling the default style. How can I achieve this?

Comment: what is the your use case and what are you expecting to gather from the events?

Comment: @charlietfl, I've updated the question, please take a look at it, thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To query command state you need to use:

```
editor.getCommand( 'bulletedlist' ).state;
```

It will return one of:

- [`CKEDITOR.TRISTATE_DISABLED`](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR-property-TRISTATE_DISABLED)
- [`CKEDITOR.TRISTATE_OFF`](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR-property-TRISTATE_OFF)
- [`CKEDITOR.TRISTATE_ON`](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR-property-TRISTATE_ON)